# How to ask CMP consent permissions after App Tracking Transparency denied on iOS?

Tags: ios, swift, gdprconsentform, apptrackingtransparency

Apple rejects the app if we show Consent Manager after the user denies App Tracking Transparency prompt. But our app is highly dependent on the CMP, and have web content integrations across the app (social media blocks). There is no CMP permissions dependent on ATT there, we don't track user's data. We ask ATT to adjust analytics only.

```
var status = await ATTrackingManager.requestTrackingAuthorization()

switch status {
case .authorized:
    // Show Consent Management Platform dialog
case .denied:
    // Want to show Show CMP dialog here too <<<<<
case .notDetermined, .restricted:
    // Do nothing
}
```

#### Apple gives this reason of the rejection

> We noticed you collect data to track after the user selects "Ask App
> Not to Track" on the App Tracking Transparency permission request.
>
> Specifically, we noticed your app accesses web content you own and
> collects cookies for tracking after the user asked you not to track
> them.
>
> ###### Next Steps
>
> To resolve this issue, please revise your app so that you do not
> collect data for tracking purposes if the user does not give
> permission for tracking.
>
> Alternatively, if you do not collect cookies for tracking purposes,
> revise the cookie prompts that appear in your app to clarify you do
> not track users.

How can we successfully pass the review in this case, and still use/show CMP if ATT was denied?